# Use of multiple language in text editor

Tags: json, phpstorm, text-editor

I have a JSON file (or any file like PHP, JavaScript, HTML, CSS) and I want to write multiple languages in that file.

```js
{
    "jokes" : {
        id: 1,
        title: "my-2nd-language" // in my case I want to use Bengali over here
    }
}
```

If I change the font of the editor the hole file language change to that font.
So all of the English languages also change to that font.

Now I want to know how I use both languages in my text editor. I am using PhpStorm as my text editor. You can suggest me any other text editor also (like VSCode, Notepad++, Sublime Text...)

Comment: Use a font that support multiple languages/your Bengali (sadly I do not know what fonts that might be). In theory Consolas should do that. P.S. In PhpStorm you may set up 2nd (fallback) font -- if some glyphs (symbols) are not found in main font, the 2nd font will be used.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the *font* to write another language. You need to choose an *encoding* for the file that supports all languages (e.g. UTF-8, especially if we're talking about JSON), and then you just write your text. Your editor will need to properly support input and display of Bengali though. Which it hopefully does without issues in this day and age if your operating system supports it.

Comment: I've created a document with [random text in several scripts](http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/) and my copy of PhpStorm running on Windows 10 displays all them just fine. (Neither my primary font nor the fallback one support those scripts.) It isn't a big sample but it suggests your problem is elsewhere.